# Adding Count Up module to custom front page

Tags: theming, javascript, 9

My end goal is to put several Count Up numbers on my custom front page. But I'm having trouble getting it implemented.

First, I installed the Count Up library (https://github.com/inorganik/CountUp.js) and put it in the libraries directory.

Then in mytheme.libraries.yml, I put

```
countup:
  version: 1.0
  js:
    /libraries/countup.js/dist/countUp.umd.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

And then in page--front.html.twig, I put

```
{{ attach_library('mytheme/countup') }}
            <div class="countup">
              <div id="transit_count">0</div>
              <script>
                $(function() {
                  let transits = new CountUp('transit_count', 6699);
                  if (!transits.error) {
                    transits.start();
                  } else {
                    console.error(transits.error);
                  }
                });
              </script>
            </div>
```

When I flushed the cache, I got this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: CountUp is not defined".

What am I missing here? I'm pretty weak at JS so it could be something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your site, is there countUp.umd.js attached? Simple solution: https://www.drupal.org/project/countup

Comment: @Nikit, yes, the script call shows up in the HTML. The Count Up Drupal module is for making the feature available to CKEditor which is not what I want to do. I did install it just in case it helped, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working sample:

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>CountUp.js</title>

       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
       <script src="dist/countUp.umd.js"></script>
     </head>

     <body>

        <div class="countup">
          <div id="transit_count">0</div>
          <script>
            (function ($) {
              let transits = new countUp.CountUp('transit_count', 6699);
              if (!transits.error) {
                transits.start();
              } else {
                console.error(transits.error);
              }
            })(jQuery);

          </script>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That works, thank you! I was hoping to do it the "Drupal way" but as long as it works I'm not going to complain.

Comment: @Chanel not sure for down vote, I am just show JS mistake, there's no Drupal way. At least, I recommend put code into js file, not in HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

You basically had it right, just a typo in your JS as the Nikit pointed out. The correct answer should include the JS in the template file.

In `mytheme.libraries.yml`:

```
countup:
  js:
    /libraries/countup.js/dist/countUp.umd.js: {}
```

Because that's there, there's no need to put it in the HEAD again.

And then in the template file, `page--front.html.twig`, put:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        let transits = new countUp.CountUp('transit_count', 6699);
        if (!transits.error) {
            transits.start();
        } else {
            console.error(transits.error);
        }
    });
</script>
```

However, you shouldn't *need* to put this in a template file, rather you should put it in a custom theme JS file(s) that deals with theme JS.